# Suche eine Quelle zu den NS-Einflüssen auf die deutsche Sprache

Tags: etymology, resource

Bei der Recherche des Wortes *Bumstinazi* stieß ich auf den [höchst interessanten Eintrag bei Ostarrichi.org](http://www.ostarrichi.org/begriff-9107-at-Bumstinazi.html):

> "Manche mögen folgendes Beispiel zurückweisen, aber es sollten jene gehört werden, die es erzählen. Bis heute ist es weit verbreitet, kleinen Kindern, die tollpatschig etwas fallen lassen, nicht mit 'Hoppala', sondern mit einem zärtlichen 'Bumstinazi' den Schrecken zu lindern. Einmal nachgefragt, erfuhr ich, daß dieses liebliche 'Bumstinazi' aus den dreißiger Jahren in Erinnerung ist, als man auf diese Weise Sprengstoffattentate der illegalen Nationalsozialisten, leicht verschlüsselt, zustimmend kommentierte. Eine Zustimmung, die sich in kindlicher Sprache konserviert und entfremdet erhalten konnte."

Nun suche ich eine möglichst aktuelle und gepflegte Onlinequelle, um mich in die Thematik einzulesen und „verdächtige“ Wörter nachschlagen zu können. Kann mir jemand helfen?

Comment: Der Zusammenhang zu den illegalen Nazis war mir bekannt, aber dass das Zustimmung ausdrückt, habe ich noch nie gehört und würde das nicht ohne weiteren Beleg glauben.

Comment: Darum such ich auch weitere Quellen und lese jetzt den Artikel aus dem es stammt. Wenn du willst berichte ich dir dann was darin steht ;)

Comment: Er zitiert dabei aus [Klemperer, Victor: "LTI". Die unbewältigte Sprache. Aus dem Notizbuch eines Philologen. München, 1969](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/LTI_%E2%80%93_Notizbuch_eines_Philologen). Ich nehme das eher als vertrauenswürdige Quelle wahr. Leider scheint es keine Bücher des Autors in der Unibibo Salzburg zu geben. Sonst wär das definitiv ein guter Startpunkt für mich.

Comment: Interessante Thematik! @Samuel, falls du etwas interessantes findest hoffe ich, dass du dich daran erinnerst: Du kannst hier _Jeopardy_ spielen. :)

Comment: Das Wort "Bumstinazi" habe ich noch nie gehört. Meine Wahrnehmung sagt zwar nichts über den Sprachgebrauch im Allgemeinen, aber es dürfte schon ein sehr selten gebrauchtes Wort sein.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Neben Klemperers **LTI** finde ich immer noch lesenwert [**Aus dem Wörterbuch des Unmenschen**](http://www.amazon.de/Aus-W%C3%B6rterbuch-Unmenschen-Dolf-Sternberger/dp/B0000BO90J) von Dolf Sternberger, Gerhard Storz und Wilhelm E. Süskind. Kriegt man derzeit nur gebraucht, fürchte ich.

Allerdings »endet« das Buch 1967 mit seiner dritten Auflage; wie aktuell das heute noch ist, muß man eben selbst einschätzen.

Zufälligerweise korrekte Daten [aus der Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolf_Sternberger):

> Es finden sich u. a. Kommentare zu folgenden Wörtern (bzw. deren spezifische Ausrichtung, also ihren Missbrauch bzw. Gebrauch im Nationalsozialismus): Anliegen, Ausrichtung, Betreuung, charakterlich, durchführen, echt, einmalig, Einsatz, Frauenarbeit, Gestaltung, herausstellen, intellektuell, Kulturschaffende, Lager, leistungsmäßig, Mädel, Menschenbehandlung, organisieren, Problem, Propaganda, querschießen, Raum, Schulung, Sektor, tragbar, untragbar, Vertreter, wissen um, Zeitgeschehen. In der dritten Auflage 1967 enthielt das Wörterbuch 33 Begriffe: Mädel wurde herausgenommen, Auftrag, Härte, Kontakte, Menschen, Ressentiments u. a. wurden hinzugefügt.

---

Ich fände in diesem Zusammenhang die Frage nach dem Einfluß totalitärer politischer Systeme allgemein auf die deutsche Sprache spannend.
Ich habe die ersten 16 Jahre meines Lebens in der DDR verbracht – bis heute schmecken einige Ausdrücke für mich seltsam: **Solidarität**, **Freundschaft**, **Kapitalismus** und selbst **Frieden** (lauter »Konzepte«).
Die subjektive Seite ist bei den Ausdrücken aus der DDR natürlich noch viel lebendiger; ihr Verschleiß läßt sich vermutlich besser mit modernen Methoden untersuchen. Bestimmt passiert das auch, da würde ich mal in die Germanistik-Ecke der nächsten Unibibliothek gucken.

Für jemanden, der Deutsch lernt, ist das vermutlich ein fürchterliches Minenfeld. Aber ich denke, einem Ausländer nimmt man Fehltritte hier nicht so krumm. Selbst die [bundesdeutsche ARGE](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jobcenter) *führt* ja heutzutage *Maßnahmen durch* – und leider trifft sie damit fast wieder den alten Kern.

Comment: Maßnahmen der Arge sind mit großer Sicherheit Verbeugungen vor Berthold Brecht (http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_Ma%C3%9Fnahme)

Comment: @user unknown Wer auch immer das Vokabular der ARGE verbrochen hat, muß natürlich ein Brechtliebhaber gewesen sein. :)

Comment: man beachte: 1930, also keine Brechtsche Kritik an der Naziherrschaft.

Comment: @user unknown Oh, du hast das ernst gemeint? Ich denke eher an der Fraenkelschen Unterschied zwischen [Maßnahmen- und Normenstaat](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernst_Fraenkel_(Politikwissenschaftler)#Exilszeit_und_sp.C3.A4tere_Jahre).

Comment: Die Arge scheint irgendwie ein Chamäleon mit häufigem Namenswechsel zu sein. Ich kannte sie schlicht als _Arbeitsamt_ und hab auch schon mal von einer _Bundesanstalt für Arbeit_ gehört. Die Betroffenen werden sicher den jeweils aktuellen Namen kennen.

Comment: Na, ich habe es nicht ernstgemeint, aber durch das Nachschlagen von "Die Maßnahme" bin ich eben darauf gekommen, dass der Begriff vor den Nazis wohl schon unangenehm im Gebrauch war. Deswegen habe ich die Entstehung um 1930 nochmal nachgeschoben. Allerdings sind ja die meisten der o.g. Begriffe nicht in der Nazizeit geprägt worden - womöglich umgeprägt?

Comment: @user unknown Ja, **umgeprägt**, oder **letzte starke Färbung** trifft es wohl am besten. Mich interessiert hierbei, wie die Bedeutung weiterwandert – oder ob die Ausdrücke für lange Zeit verbrannt sind.

Comment: @toscho Auch wenn die ARGE-"Maßnahme" wahrscheinlich in vollem Ernst ersonnen  wurde: Der Staat ist manchmal durchaus zu Selbstironie in der Lage. Heißt doch die offizielle Software für die Steuererklärung [ELSTER.](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELSTER)  :)

Comment: Wow supertolle Antwort! Ich hoff ich finde das Buch irgendwo :) Der Einfluss totalitärer Systeme auf Sprachen allgemein ist ja ein Riesenthema, nicht umsonst ist das ein guter Teil jeder Dystopie. Könntest du bitte noch ARGE verlinken/erläutern? Einem Nicht-BRDler sagt das garnichts ^^

Comment: @SamuelHerzog Die ARGE ist eine Art Arbeitsamt zweiter Klasse. Ich habe einen Link auf die Jobcenter gesetzt, die regionalen Instanzen dieser Behörde.

Comment: oha! Wieder etwas neues gelernt. Danke!

Comment: Mangels anderer Antworten, vielen Dank für deine Hilfe, ich bin mir sicher die Information von dir stimmt so :)

Answer (score 1):

Eine "möglichst aktuelle und gepflegte Online"-Quelle habe ich nicht anzubieten, aber eine punktgenaue Analyse nationalsozialistischen Sprachgebrauchs durch einen Zeitgenossen:

["(Die) Dritte Walpurgisnacht"](https://kraus1933.ace.oeaw.ac.at/index.html) von Karl Kraus